# Groovy closure to find similar user records

Tags: groovy, closures

I have LawfirmUser entity with `FirstName`, `LastName` and `userId` attributes below is some sample data of LawfirmUser

```
FirstName      LastName     userId
----------   -----------  ----------
Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
Demo            test3         6 
Demo            test4         7
```

I have a groovy list lawfirmUsersList(of LawfirmUsers) and am trying to write a closure to find all the records having same First and Last names but different userIds

the closure should print below data

```
FirstName      LastName     userId
----------   -----------  ----------
Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
```

Am pretty beginer to Groovy and closures stuff, Could someone please help me with the closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately don't know where the input comes from but here is how it can be done (input parsed from string) - see the comments for clarification. Feel free to ask in case of any problems.

```
def input ="""FirstName      LastName     userId
----------   -----------  ----------
Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
Demo            test3         6 
Demo            test4         7"""

input.split('\n')[2..-1] // split input with '\n' and ignore the first two lines
.collect { //transform each line to an instance of Map
    def splitted = it.split()
    [firstName: splitted[0], lastName: splitted[1], userId: splitted[2]]
}
.groupBy { //group maps by pair 'firstNamelastName' - here same firstnames and lastnames are found
    it.firstName + it.lastName 
}
.values() //take values for keys
.findAll { //ignore single entries e.g. 'Demotest4'
    it.size() > 1 
}.flatten() // remove list nesting
.each { println it} //print found lines

null
```

**UPDATE** (after comments)

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

def input ="""Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
Demo            test3         6 
Demo            test4         7"""

@ToString
class LawfirmUser {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Integer userId
}

def users = input.split('\n').collect {
    def splitted = it.split()
    new LawfirmUser(firstName: splitted[0], lastName: splitted[1], userId: splitted[2].toInteger())
}

def filtered = users.groupBy { it.firstName + it.lastName }.values().findAll { it.size() > 1 }.flatten()
assert filtered.size() == 5
filtered.each {
    println it
}

null
```

Comment: I have a queryService which returns all the records of LawfirmUser like this `def lawfirmUserList = queryService.query("LawfirmUser").list()`

Comment: @RanPaul: is that what You're looking for? It'd better idea to make to query directly on DB.

Comment: @RanPaul has this question been answered? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked through an example here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5745580152193024

which I think answers the core of your question, i.e. how to use closures and Groovy's functional extensions to the collections API to manipulate the data. This is the sort of problem that can be solved in several ways, hopefully mine will give you some insight into how idiomatic groovy collections work.

Code inline for reference:

```
//your raw data as groovy maps, which will behave like objects
def lawFirms=[
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test1",userId:1],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test1",userId:2],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test1",userId:3],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test2",userId:4],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test2",userId:5],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test3",userId:6],
    [firstName:"Demo",lastName:"test4",userId:7]
]
//get a cont of entries by lastname
def counts=lawFirms.countBy{ firm -> firm.lastName }   //[test1:3, test2:2, test3:1, test4:1]
//filter out only those with count > 1 i.e. not unique
def hasMoreThanOne = counts.findAll{ k,v -> v>1 }      //[test1:3, test2:2]
//construct a map with each lastname that has >1 entries as keys, and list of all matching firms as entry
//(not simplest for just printing, but seems like a good way to organise results in general)
def multipleGroups = hasMoreThanOne.collectEntries([:]){ k,v ->
    [k,lawFirms.findAll{ firm -> k==firm.lastName }]
}    /*[test1:[
            [firstName:Demo, lastName:test1, userId:1],
            [firstName:Demo, lastName:test1, userId:2],
            [firstName:Demo, lastName:test1, userId:3]
        ],
        test2:[
            [firstName:Demo, lastName:test2, userId:4],
            [firstName:Demo, lastName:test2, userId:5]
        ]
    ]*/

//iterate through data structure printing out results
multipleGroups.each{ k,v ->
    v.each{ firm ->
        println "${firm.firstName},${firm.lastName},${firm.userId}"
    }
}
```